# How to receive bare strings from a dictionary, without double quotes or brackets or parenthesis at the end?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, quotes, strip

Given a dictionary, how can I get a 'raw' list of values from the dictionary? The desired result does not contain brackets or parentheses or double quotes at the end, it only contains single quotes around each value. The desired result looks like:

```
result = 'yellow', 'green', 'white'
```

I'm open to a recommendation for how to set the dictionary to ease obtaining the desired result output. The dictionary can be composed of key-value pairs where the pairs are dictionaries AND lists or tuples or sets.

This solution worked in testing and I'm wondering if there's something more pythonic and more robust than using `print` so that I can use the result beyond just printing it out in testing:

```
Dict_w_tuple_values = dict(
   dictionary={
    'fruits':{
        'type':['c'],
        'colors':('yellow', 'green', 'white'),
    },
)

result = print(", ".join( repr(e) for e in list(Dict_w_tuple_values['dictionary']['fruits']['colors'])))
```

Originally I had this dictionary:

```
Dict_w_list_values = dict(
   dictionary={
    'fruits':{
        'type':['c'],
        'colors':['yellow', 'green', 'white'],
    },
)
```

...and tried list comprehensions, `.join`, `eval(list_object)`,  `.strip`, `.lstrip` , `findall`, `str(list_object)[1:-1]`, `re.sub`, `replace`, `join` with `map`.

None of these has worked. I saw some opportunities with using regex but didn't get the desired result.

Ultimately, I would like to use the result to populate parameters via 
`.format(**Dict_w_tuple_values)`.

The parameters when populated should be:

```
'yellow', 'green', 'white'
```

Not

```
"'yellow', 'green', 'white'"
```

or

```
["'yellow', 'green', 'white'"]
```

nor

```
("'yellow', 'green', 'white'")
```

Comment: You do not have a list object. You have a string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the `list_object` string and applying regexes to it, why don't you do this?

```
list_string = ', '.join(DictVariables['dictionary']['fruits']['colors'])
```

---

If you need single quotes around each string:

```
list_string = "'{}'".format(
    "', '".join(DictVariables['dictionary']['fruits']['colors']))
```

This adds single quotes between each element (`', '`) and then adds the remaining outer ones with the `format`

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you. This is a more direct solution. After testing again, I see that I do need single quotes around each of the color values. Can you recommend how to use your method while maintaining just the single quotes around the color values?

Comment: this is close. 
`result = ', '.join(DictVariables['dictionary']['fruits']['colors']) `
>>> `'yellow, green, white'`

`result = "'{}'".format(
    "', '".join(DictVariables['dictionary']['fruits']['colors']))`

>>>  `"'yellow', 'green', 'white'"`

`result = "', '".join(DictVariables['dictionary']['fruits']['colors']))`

>>>  `"yellow', 'green', 'white"`

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function to remove the [] from list.
below is the code for your reference.

```
a.replace('[','').replace(']','')
```

the double quotes makes the list to string so we wont able to remove that.let me know reason for using the double we can solve this

Comment: hello Muraldihar, thank you for your suggestion. I've updated the description. I hope it better explains the code needs and purpose.